# Google Play store coming soon

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I have been asked to set up a google play store account/listing for an app that is in early stages of development. The company simply wants a link with some screenshots up that they can point to for marketing purposes.

I want to build a listing that just says Coming Soon and has a description and screen shots. I was wondering if this is an option or do I have to upload some sort of APK on the listing.

Comment: You must have an app on the play store to be registered as an app developer.

Comment: Placing a non-functioning or stub-app into the store could run against [Google policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html). I'd double-check... also, keep in mind that it will open you up to (negative) feedback from frustrated customers, especially when the "soon" turns into "eventually."

Comment: We can see now "Coming Soon" option for apps on play store. check this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fireball&hl=en  How can we achieve this?